# Map over IO [Int] in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci, io-monad

I'd like to know how to map over an `IO [Int]` in GHCI.

```hs
λ: :{
λ| th :: IO [Int]
λ| th = pure [1, 2, 3, 4]
λ| :}
λ: th
[1,2,3,4]
λ: :t th
th :: IO [Int]
λ: map (+2) th
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[b]’ with actual type ‘IO [Int]’
    • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘th’
      In the expression: map (+ 2) th
```

Desired result:

```hs
λ: res = map (+2) th -- <-- some working version of this
λ: res
[3, 4, 5, 6]
λ: :t res
res :: IO [Int]
```

The solution is probably very obvious but somehow I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to performing a mapping over the values of a [**`Functor`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor). Since `IO` is a functor, you can thus use this to *post-process* the result of an `IO` action:

```
Prelude> fmap (map (+2)) th
[3,4,5,6]
```

You can also use the infix operator [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) which is an alias:

```
Prelude> map (+2) <$> th
[3,4,5,6]
```